# Parse xml elements and their attributes in LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Today is the first time I ever expose to LINQ so to say I am newbie is an understatement.. So what I am trying to do is to parse the value of the STAT elements and their attributes. My sample XML looks like this.

```
<ILS TGT="00-25-CE-94-00-05" PID="404001C5354144E4DA40E01F5000002" ORGCODE="00010019" xmlns="Mytest/v1.0">
  <STAT TIME="000000018" TYPE="SYS" FIELD="PWR_V" VAL="1196"/>
  <STAT TIME="000000018" TYPE="CAN" NID="65" FIELD="LAST_EC" VAL="EC_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT"/>
  <STAT TIME="000000018" TYPE="NWK" FIELD="W_RSSI" VAL="-85"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000017" TYPE="ACC" SUBTYPE="GRANTED" CRDT="DPIN" CRED1="1212"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000018" TYPE="ACC" SUBTYPE="GRANTED" CRDT="DPIN" CRED1="1212" CRED2="2345"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000019" TYPE="ACC" SUBTYPE="DENIED" CRDT="OCRD" CRED1="0000DE0871"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000020" TYPE="ACC" SUBTYPE="GRANTED" CRDT="DCRD" CRED1="0000DE0871" CRED2="2345"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000021" TYPE="CFG" SUBTYPE="RELOCK_TIME" VAL="300"/>
  <EVT TIME="0000000022" TYPE="LOG" SUBTYPE="HB_TIMEOUT" VAL="65"/>
</ILS>
```

So upon searching around on this board I found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077425/linq-to-xml-extracting-attributes-and-elements) which answers my question.  However, I applied that and for some reason I can't get any result at all, can anybody take a quick look and point to what I have done wrong?

```
public static void ParseXML(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

            XElement root = xDoc.Root;

            Console.WriteLine("TGT: " + root.Attribute("TGT").Value + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("PID: " + root.Attribute("PID").Value + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("ORGCODE: " + root.Attribute("ORGCODE").Value + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("xmlns: " + root.Attribute("xmlns").Value + "\n");

            //Everything above this line is good, I was able to get the print out.

            var eleSTAT = from node in xDoc.Descendants("STAT")
                           select new
                           {
                               attrTIME = node.Attribute("TIME").Value,
                               attrTYPE = node.Attribute("TYPE").Value,
                               attrFIELD = node.Attribute("FIELD").Value,
                               attrVAL = node.Attribute("VAL").Value,
                           };

            //When I run my code, it never got into this foreach loop, aas if eleSTAT is empty
            foreach (var s in eleSTAT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TIME: " + s.attrTIME + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("TYPE: " + s.attrTYPE + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("FIELD: " + s.attrFIELD + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("VAL: " + s.attrVAL + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


    }
```

And my last question, since I have multiple STAT element, would the above work? I want to have all 4 STAT elements and their attributes return to me.  I figure this has to be done in some type of loop?  am I correct in saying my foreach loop should already does this?

Comment: Empty LINQ queries are a common question on SO.  This answer here should help solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2340411/250725

Comment: To answer your last question you added in the edit.... once you get your namespace issue resolved in the query, you should return a collection of 4 objects, one for each `<STAT>` element.  The LINQ query is effectively doing the loop for you to retrieve each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the XML namespace to [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx).

Change your code like this:

```
...
XNamespace xmlns = "Mytest/v1.0";
var eleSTAT = from node in xDoc.Descendants(xmlns + "STAT")
...
```