# What is wrong with this XML that is preventing linq from working?

Tags: xml, linq

```
    Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(xmlFile)
    Dim stuff =
        From item In root.Elements("abc") Select item

    Debug.Print(stuff.Count)
```

and the contents of the XML are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <abc xmlns="foo">1</abc>
  <abc xmlns="foo">2</abc>
  <abc xmlns="foo">3</abc>
</Workbook>
```

If I remove **xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"** the beginning of the the **Workbook** tag, I get the correct result of **3**

**ETA** What do I do if I have another namespace embedded, in this case "foo"

Comment: The `abc` elements are in the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet` See here how to handle namespaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse xml elements and their attributes in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052958/parse-xml-elements-and-their-attributes-in-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find an element with a name `abc` *without any namespace*. The `xmlns=...` part of the parent element sets the default namespace for descendant elements.

You need:

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
...
Dim stuff = root.Elements(ns + "abc")
```

Note that there's no point in using a query expression here - if you're just doing `From x in y Select x` you can just use `y` instead...

Comment: *Assuming VB supports the overloaded + operator in the same way as C#* Yes, it does.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Thanks - I've removed that bit of the answer then :)